# session_save_path setting failed

Tags: php, apache, session, configuration

I am unable to set my custom php session saving path from inside an php script.

```
ini_set('session.save_path', "/var/www/domain.com/sessions");
echo ini_get('session.save_path')."<br />";

session_save_path("/var/www/domain.com/sessions");
echo session_save_path()."<br />";
```

The above code prints

```
/var/www/domain.com/tmp

/var/www/domain.com/tmp
```

which means the default settings persist.

I am very limited to any workarounds:
1) no access to php.ini
2) htaccess causing error 500 - php_value directives are disabled

So I really need to overwrite the session storage from inside of php scripts.

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

(The directory /var/www/domain.com/sessions exists under owner/group = root/root, having the write permissions properly set for others. Exactly the same way as the default tmp dir.)

Comment: why do you need to change this setting?

Comment: For subdomain-specific session separation.

Comment: is it possible to set the domain of the session cookie? would that help? BTW: have you tried [session_save_path](http://php.net/session_save_path)

Comment: you could try to change the `session.cookie_domain` ini-setting to something `subdomain.example.com`. If you do so, the session cookie is only valid on this subdomain.

Comment: Well, this wouldnt help me much, because I need to set-up per-subdomain session expiration (= independent garbage collection). AFAIK Separating the session files to different folders is the only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache is currently running PHP as PHP_MOD.

AFAIK there is no solution until PHP goes CGI or FASTCGI.